# Laravel: how to use /admin

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create pages for admin and I want to use dashboard in *localhost:8000/admin* url...but the page is showing a display [Not Found Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESCcT.png).

Please tell me what should I do to resolve this

Comment: You should give us more info about your files, I guess :-/

Answer (score 0):

You need somethig like this in your /app/Http/routes.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' =>'admin', 'namespace' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {

    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index');
    // .....

});
```

Comment: please tell me what is the reason for such page occured

Comment: please provide more info

Comment: please check the screen shot that i have attched

Comment: do you define that route in routes.php ?

Comment: With this first : Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index'); 404. your other pages router is ok ?

Comment: 'namespace' => 'Admin'

Comment: apache ?  enable rewrite ?